# aws QuickSight could not generate any output column after applying transformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to create a visualization using aws quicksight, I've done it before using the same data source and tables.

Right now when I try to run simple query
`select * from table order by time desc limit 10;`
it outputs `QuickSight could not generate any output column after applying transformation.`

When I run same query in aws athena it works fine.

I have my data in SPICE.

EDIT: I've just re-created my dataset in quicksight and it is now working... Still want to know what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in QuickSight when I created a new custom SQL data source getting data out of Spectrum. And I also got it to work by re-creating the data source.